# Issue with react i18next singular and plural, always return plural value

Tags: next.js, i18next, react-i18next

I have some confuse situation with i18next. when i use english language it totally correct. but when I change language to zh, It always return plural value event the value is singular.

I try to upgrade dependencies, change config, but still not working.

I have provided a sample code in the following link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-plurals-forked-jgulw6?file=/public/locales/zh/translation.json

Config

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    ns: ["common"],
    defaultNS: "common",
    resources,
    fallbackNS: "en",
    supportedLngs: ["en", "zh"],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },
    react: {
      bindI18n: "loaded languageChanged"
    },
    returnEmptyString: false,
    nsSeparator: false
  });

export default i18n;
```

Dependencies version:

```
i18next             21.3.1
intl-pluralrules    1.3.1
react               17.0.0
react-i18next.      11.12.0
```

Comment: I'm having sex with exactly same issue right now. I have latest versions of react, and other dependencies and issue is the same.

Comment: The thing is that in English translation it could be _one, _many, but in ZH it could be something like _sole, _others. These keys are different for every language...

Comment: Looks like in your example if you click lang selector, EN it will convert keys to correct translation. As for Chineese looks like it also is correct (it thinks so)

but indeed it looks like as if it doesn't work. 


To get pluralisation keys try to use:
const pr = new Intl.PluralRules('ro'); //try zh, ru, en locales
pr.select(100); // try different numbers

Answer (score 3):

***It's not a bug, but a feature***

Different languages (locales) have different applicable plural suffixes.

You can use only allowed suffixes or i18n fallbacks to another (if existed) namespace.

Read https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/plurals
and use (provided by i18next, you can find the link on previous page) https://jsfiddle.net/6bpxsgd4 to check what suffixes your desired language (locale) supports.

For example:

- English (en): _one, _other;
- Chinese (zh): _other;
- Russian (ru): _one, _few, _many.

So you need to keep it in mind, when you provide translation keys.
I also encountered similar problem when I tried to use "month_one" and "month_other" for "en" and "ru":

[image]

All because "ru" don't support "_other" suffix. The problem is solved when I used just "month" and "month_one" keys.

For you case - Chinese (zh) only supports "_other" suffix (or just dont use suffix at all):

```
{
  "test": "測試",
  "month_one": "{{ count }} 月" // won't work, because there is no "_one" for "zh"
  "month_other": "{{ count }} 月s" // or "month": "{{ count }} 月s"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. The JS fiddle was very helpful too!